# "python --version" not working even after installation and adding path to env variables

Tags: python, path, stable-diffusion

When typing "python --version" into cmd, I get the following error:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

"py --version" works, but I need it to work with the "python" command instead of "py" because stable diffusion uses "python" to execute scripts

Here is where my python is installed:

C:\Users\Ruben Work\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

And I have added the following to my "Path" variable for the user and system:

C:\Users\Ruben Work\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
C:\Users\Ruben Work\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\

Comment: Try to check if your PATH is set up correctly by typing `where python` in cmd and If python is found, it should print the path to the executable. If it's not found, then your PATH is not set up correctly.

Comment: It works, I got some additional Path's, but even adding these to the Path variable still gives the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it struggled with the path variable due to me having 2 user profiles on my PC, even though both have full admin rights. I installed python on my main profile, and it solved this issue.